# How to trigger contact to enter journey when SalesCloud data is modified

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, sales-cloud

I'm building a journey that sends emails to different contacts once one of the two conditions is modified.

However, after I modified the 1st condition in SalesCloud, the contact did not enter the journey as expected.

Could someone kindly tell me if I'm missing anything in the setup?

Should I modify 2 conditions as well in order to make it work?

The data is pulled straight from SalesCloud. So, it's expected the contact to enter when I change the conditions on SalesCloud's end.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you just update the 1st condition and saved it? Or did you set it to something not matching your criteria, saved it, changed it to the value matching your criteria, and saved again?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Actually, I toggled the 1st condition to `False` (not matched the condition), and changed it back again to `True`, to match the condition in Journey Entry Data. Does it affect the outcome?

Comment: Did you save it between each toggle? You need to do this, if the trigger is to fire.

Comment: I mean, yes. I saved it and waited. But the contact did not enter the journey,

Comment: When you go to Journey History, do you see any „ContactAttempted” or any statuses at all for this journey? Do you have any other SF-triggered journeys in this BU that work?

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj I didn't see any Contact attempts in Journey History either.

Comment: Do you have any other journeys triggered by SF data that work in this BU, or is this your first attempt to set one up? Trying to determine if this might be a Connector issue or a Journey issue.

Comment: @zuzannamj, it's the 1st journey that I pull data from. I think it's the Journey issue. The toggle condition in SalesCloud didn't trigger the Entry criteria, hence no data entered the journey. At least that's what I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your issue is the use of an OR condition. When you are testing your Entry Event, you need to follow a specific process:

Observe your journey's entry criteria. In your case, you are looking at two fields, let's call these **Field1__c** and **Field2__c**. Your entry criteria expects EITHER **Field1__c** being *True* OR **Field2__c** being *Active*.

To ensure a record is properly evaluated for entry, it needs to transition from what I would call an *unaccepted* state, where it would not match your entry criteria, and into an *accepted* state, where it matches your criteria.

In your case, since you are utilizing an OR operator, switching just one of the fields into an *unaccepeted* state is not sufficient. Let's say **Field1__c** is switched to *False* while **Field2__c** is still set to *Active*. Saving the record will NOT move it into *unaccepted* state. You will need to switch both fields, so **Field1__c** is *False* and **Field2__c** in *Inactive* before saving it.

Once saved, you can now change one of the values to match your entry criteria (e.g. by switching **Field1__c** to *True*). When your record is saved, it should match the entry criteria and enter your journey.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the condition **Field1__c** into `Entry Criteria`, and then ** Field2__c** into `Filter Criteria`to eliminate the OR operator. But nothing works :(